How does \if:w work?
I cannot work out how \if:w works and LaTeX3's manual does not show any example on how to use it:
I want to check whether the document is currently in oneside or twoside mode:
\if@twoside
    Twoside mode
\else
    Oneside mode
\fi

LaTeX2 works but I cannot convert it to LaTeX3 code; my current code:
\if:w \if@twoside \relax
    Twoside mode
\else:
    Oneside mode
\fi:

I checked out latex.ltx for examples to get an understand for \if:w's syntax but they make no sense to me at all.

Use \legacy_if:nTF{@twoside}{true}{false}.

\if:w is just \if in classic tex syntax (so unrelated to this kind of test, it tests two character tokens)

Thanks for claraification! Problem is solved

If I type latexdef if:w in a terminal window, I get
\if:w:
\if

which means that \if:w is an alternative name for the TeX primitive \if. You may look at How does \if work? for detailed descriptions.
There's a reason why the manual for expl3 doesn't show examples of usages for \if:w and it's that expl3 strives to avoid primitive conditionals in code preferring constructs of the form
<expl3 conditional>:<args>TF <condition(s)> { <true text> } { <false text>}

No \else: nor \fi:. Of course, who knows how to use primitive TeX conditionals may be tempted to use them. It's much better not to, unless efficiency is a primary concern for some complicated function.
It shouldn't go without mention that \if (and \if:w, of course) is quite delicate, as it performs macro expansion of the tokens following it until finding two unexpandable ones, which compares the character codes of.
 The TeXbook says that unexpandable control sequences are assigned code 256, but I believe it's better to say –1, which can't be a character code in any engine.
What's the TF form of \if:w? It's
\token_if_equal_charcode:NNTF

but in this case the tokens to be compared must be passed without expecting the macro expansion that TeX performs when dealing with \if.
A good rule of thumb is that if an expl3 function has w in its signature, there will be higher level functions that don't use w. See, for instance, \exp_after:wN (that's \expandafter renamed) and the wealth of \exp_args:<signature> functions.
Your attempt is bound to failure: indeed \if@twoside is either \iftrue or \iffalse, which are expandable conditionals. Suppose \if@twoside is \iftrue. Then we have
\if:w \iftrue \relax
    Twoside mode
\else:
    Oneside mode
\fi:

TeX will expand \iftrue leaving
\if:w \relax Twoside Mode \else: Oneside Mode \fi:

but \else: and \fi: are labeled as pertaining to \iftrue. An unfinished conditional ensues: the test is false because \relax and T have different character code. TeX will remove the “true text” and won't find a matching \fi.
Similarly in the case when \if@twoside is \iffalse; here you get
\if:w Oneside Mode \fi:

again with \fi; labeled to pertain to \iffalse. Still an unfinished conditional.
(Thanks to wipet for spotting a mistake.)
You can test conditionals defined with \newif, such as \if@twoside, with \legacy_if:nTF
\legacy_if:nTF { @twoside } { Twoside~mode } { Oneside~mode }

and you can even dispense with \makeatletter.

If \if@twoside has meaning \iftrue or \iffalse then it is exapndable. If \if:w has meaning \if, then it expands \if@twoside before the \if test is performed.

@wipet Thanks for noting. I'll fix it.
